# Removing document root from file path Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to display an image but I am running into the error of `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/public/images/profile/jimmy/status/boned.jpg` in the browser console. What I am trying to do is use the base path provided by Zend Framework 2 but I'm retrieving the images in the model so (as far as I know), I can't use `$this->basePath()` like I would in the view.

This is my json string I am returning but would like to just be able to return `/images/profile/jimmy/status/boned.jpg` and whatever other images are in there.

I'm getting all the files outside of the directory 'status'. I am trying to get the files inside the status directory. When I did a `var_dump` this is what I get `string(43) "C:\xampp\htdocs/public/images/profile/jimmy"` I'm unclear why it is omitting the status directory after '/jimmy'

json string being returned:

`{"feed":{"username":"Timmy","status":["this is jimmy, test"],"images":["videos","status","sithtoon.jpg","sith.jpg","edited_photos","diploma.jpg","current","albums","Screenshot_2016-08-09_21_28_13_361272.jpg","Screenshot_2016-08-05_17_55_48_500802.jpg","515gIIJ-Imgur.png",".htaccess"]}}`

Here is the relevant PHP code (in the model):

```
public function listFriendsStatus()
{
    $user_id = $this->getUserId()['id'];

    // get the friend ids based on user id
    // and then compare the friend id to the id in status table
    $friend_query = new Select('friends');

    $friend_query->columns(array('friend_id'))
    ->where(array('user_id' => $user_id));  

    $query = $this->sql->getAdapter()->query(
        $this->sql->buildSqlString($friend_query),
        Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE
    );

    if ($query->count() > 0) {
        $friend_id = array();

        foreach ($query as $result) {
            $friend_id[] = $result['friend_id'];
        }


        $status = new Select('status');

        $status->columns(array('status'))
        ->where(array('id' => $friend_id)); 

        $status_query = $this->sql->getAdapter()->query(
            $this->sql->buildSqlString($status),
            Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE
        );

        if ($status_query->count() > 0) {
            // check if a image was used
            $members = new Select('members');

            $members->columns(array('username'))
            ->where(array('id' => $friend_id));

            $image_query = $this->sql->getAdapter()->query(
                $this->sql->buildSqlString($members),
                Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE
            );

            if ($image_query->count() > 0) {
                foreach ($image_query as $value) {
                    if (is_dir(getcwd() . '/images/profile/' . $value['username'] . '/status/')) {
                        $status_dir = pathinfo(getcwd() . '/images/profile/' . $value['username'] . '/status/');
                    }
                }


                $images = array();

                chdir($status_dir['dirname']);

                var_dump($status_dir['dirname']);

                // retrieve the image inside the status directory
                foreach (array_diff(scandir($status_dir['dirname'], 1), array('.', '..')) as $values) {
                    $images[] = $values;    
                }
            } else {
                throw new FeedException("The user does not exist in the user table.");
            }

            $status = array();

            // get all the statuses
            foreach ($status_query as $rows) {
                $status[] = $rows['status'];    
            }

            return array('username' => ucfirst($value['username']), 'status' => $status, 'images' => $images); // how to just get the basePath path with zf2
        } else {
            throw new FeedException("No status was found for your friends.");
        }
     } else {
        throw new FeedException(sprintf("Could not locate any friends for %s", $this->user));
     }
}
```

controller code:

```
public function getfriendstatusAction()
{
    $layout = $this->layout();
    $layout->setTerminal(true);

    $view_model = new ViewModel();
    $view_model->setTerminal(true);

    try {
        echo json_encode(array('feed' => $this->getStatusService()->listFriendsStatus()));
    } catch (FeedException $e) {
        echo json_encode(array('fail' => $e->getMessage()));
    }

    return $view_model;
}
```

jquery code:

```
$.getJSON('/members/feed/get-friend-status', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        $('.w3-container.w3-card-2.w3-white.w3-round.w3-margin').find('h4').html(data[i].username);
        $('.w3-container.w3-card-2.w3-white.w3-round.w3-margin').find('p').html(data[i].status);
        $('.w3-container.w3-card-2.w3-white.w3-round.w3-margin').find('img').attr('src', data[i].images);
    });
}).fail(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

I've been trying to use other directory functions provided with PHP but if I try anything, I run into the error directory could not be found. Basically what I am trying to do is use the similiar approach of `$this->basePath()` but in a model.

I hope that is clear enough..

Thanks!

Here is a screenshot of what I'm getting and how I want to get the status directory, not the directory outside of it.

[image]

Comment: Have you had a look at [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)? Within the project `/public` should be the root for relative paths. If you'd request a file/image using `$this->basePath(pathinfo($file)['basename'])` you should get a relative path to the specific file, based upon usage of the `/public` directory. If the file resides "somewhere" within the `/public` folder, you should add this, e.g.: `$this->basePath('/images/profiles/' . pathinfo($file)['basename'])`

Comment: but can I do that in a model? I'm not doing it in a controller or a view.

Comment: I'm getting this `string(43) "C:\xampp\htdocs/public/images/profile/jimmy"` when I try. `foreach ($image_query as $value) {
                        if (is_dir(getcwd() . '/public/images/profile/' . $value['username'] . '/status/')) {
                            $status_dir = pathinfo(getcwd() . '/public/images/profile/' . $value['username'] . '/status/');
                        }
                    }`

Comment: kind of confused why it doesn't include /status/

Comment: If you're not doing it in a view, why do you use jQuery code? That makes no sense. Why would you "display an image", as you said in the first sentence, not in a view? //// What you should be doing is making sure that the file exists in the Controller, you can do this with a simple `if(file_exists(getcwd() . '/images/profile/' . $fileName)) {..}`. Also, in the `/public/index.php` you'll find a declaration setting the working directory to `/public`, so you need not use `/public` in your paths.

Comment: After making sure the file exists, pass it along. Such as with a Controller return statement like this: `return ['image' => $fileName];`. Then use `$fileName` in your view. Use the basePath ViewHelper to print the correct path, like so: `<?= $this->basePath('/images/profile/' . $fileName) ?>

Comment: The model is handling it but the controller is calling the model's function.

Comment: I added the full code in hopes that might help.

Comment: @Nukeface if I omit the public folder, it cannot find the image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an idea.
In your code is:

```
$status_dir = pathinfo(getcwd() . '/images/profile/' . $value['username'] . '/status/');
// ..............
chdir($status_dir['dirname']);
var_dump($status_dir['dirname']);
```

Try:
    `var_dump($status_dir);`

I guess 'status' will be in 'basename' and / or in 'filename'
`pathinfo` gets last segment of argument string path as 'basename'.
Pathinfo only parses string as path and return array info, don't check it for isDir or isFile. Your correct chdir should looks like `chdir($status_dir['dirname'] . '/' . $status_dir['basename'] );` if you need use of pathinfo.

In other words: dirname of 'images/profile/jimmy/status' is 'images/profile/jimmy' and its a reason why you don't see status in `var_dump($status_dir['dirname'])` and why `chdir($status_dir['dirname'])` not working correctly.

Comment: that did the trick, only thing I need now to do is to return the path so it will load in the view correctly. This is what I have in place `return array('username' => ucfirst($value['username']), 'status' => $status, 'images' => $status_dir['dirname'] . '/' . $status_dir['basename'] . '/' . $images);` but its giving me an array to string conversion error. I just want to include the directory with the images so it will load in the view correctly.

Comment: $images - is an array. You are mixed string concatenation (`'images' => $status_dir['dirname'] . '/' . $status_dir['basename'] . '/'`) with an array (`$images`)

Comment: yeah, thought so, i just want to include the path and the images.

Comment: populate $images array eg: `$images_path = $status_dir['dirname'] . '/' . $status_dir['basename'] . '/';
foreach (array_diff(scandir($images_path, 1), array('.', '..')) as $values) {
  $images[] = **$images_path .** $values;
}
return array('username' => ucfirst($value['username']), 'status' => $status, 'images' => $images);`
OR
`foreach (array_diff(scandir($images_path, 1), array('.', '..')) as $values) {
  $images[] = $values;
}
return array('username' => ucfirst($value['username']), 'status' => $status, 'images' => $images, 'images_path' => $images_path);`

Comment: why the two **?

Comment: ** for bold comment formating (won't work in block code) - ignore this. RAW value is: { $images[] = $images_path . $values; }

Comment: still getting the error `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/public/images/profile/jimmy/status/boned.jpg`. I know it would work if I could get ride of file:///C:/xampp/htdocs

Comment: Try to remove `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/public` from url (remove getcwd()  from status_dir). `Not allowed to load local resource` can be a result of security policy of browser. Use relative path OR put `http://localhost` before `/images/....`

Comment: put `foreach ($image_query as $value) {
                        if (is_dir('images/profile/' . $value['username'] . '/status/')) {
                            $status_dir = pathinfo('images/profile/' . $value['username'] . '/status/');
                        }
                    }` 
error: `Warning: scandir(//,//): The specified path is invalid. (code: 161) in C:\xampp\htdocs\module\Members\src\Members\Model\FeedModel.php on line 117

Warning: scandir(//): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\module\Members\src\Members\Model\FeedModel.php on line 117`

Comment: OK - for scaninng Filesystem you need real dir, for url relative. Does it (or something similar) `foreach ($image_query as $value) {
 $images = array();
 $statusDir = '/images/profile/' . $value['username'] . '/status/';
 $realDir = getcwd() . $statusDir;
 if (is_dir($realDir) {
  foreach (array_diff(scandir($realDir, 1), array('.', '..')) as $values) {
   $images[] = $statusDir . $values;
  }
 }
}` solve your problem ?

Comment: just returning blank..

https://imgur.com/VVZ4Loq        https://imgur.com/S4g5YoL

Comment: put `$images = array();` before `if ($query->count() > 0) {` in your current return $images is out of scopes

Comment: What you have in `.../images/profile/timmy/status` ? in return feed username is Timmy and images is blank array - looks like there is no files in Timmy/status dir.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166917/discussion-between-slawitdev-and-user2101411).